# How to show existence and uniqueness of an $f: R(\omega) \to \omega$, where $R(\omega)$ is the cumulative hierarchy?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

**My questions**
For part A (see below), is my reasoning correct? Is it enough to just show that $f(x) \in \omega \ \ \forall x \in R(\omega)$? I'm very new to axiomatic set theory, in particular to the cumulative hierarchy, and I don't feel I have a good grasp of it at all yet.

For part B, I don't even understand what $g(n,m)$ means. It looks like $g:\omega \to \omega$ is a function of two variables, which doesn't make sense. Could anyone elucidate?

Thanks in advance!

**The problem**
-*Part A*-
Show that there is one, and only one, function $f: R(\omega) \to \omega$ satisfying
$$f(x) = \sum_{y\in x} 2^{f(y)}$$
for each $x \in R(\omega)$. Here $R(\omega)$ is the first infinite level in the cumulative
hierarchy.
Show that this function is a bijection.

-*Part B*-
Find a function $g : \omega \to \omega$ such that for all $n$ and $m$ in $\omega$ and for $x$ and $y$ in $R(\omega)$ with $n = f(x)$ and $m = f(y)$ we have that $$f(\langle x, y\rangle) = g(n,m).$$

**My attempt at a solution**

*Existence of function*
By induction: We have $f(0) = 0 \in \omega$. Assume $f(x) \in \omega \ \ \forall x \in R(\alpha)$, and let $x' \in R(\alpha + 1)$. Now $x' \subset R(\alpha)$ so for any $y \in x'$ we would have $f(y) \in \omega$, and thus $f(x') = \sum_{y\in x'} 2^{f(y)} \in \omega$.

*Uniqueness*
Also by induction: Assume $f, g$ both satisfy the criterion. We have $f(0) = 0 = g(0)$. Assume $f(x) = g(x) \ \ \forall x \in R(\alpha)$, and let $x' \in R(\alpha + 1)$. Again we would have $x' \subset R(\alpha)$, and thus $f(x') = \sum_{y\in x'} 2^{f(y)} = \sum_{y\in x'} 2^{g(y)} = g(x')$, so $f(x) = g(x) \ \ \forall x \in R(\omega)$.

*Prove $f$ is a bijection*

- Given an $\alpha \in \omega$, we can write it as $\alpha = 2^{m_1} + \dots + 2^{m_k}$, $m_1 < \dots < m_k$, where $m_i \in \omega \ \ \forall i$. We then have that $x = \{m_1, \dots , m_k\} \subset R(m_k + 1)$ which means that $x \in R(m_k+2)$. Thus we have found $x \in R(\omega)$ s.t. $f(x) = \alpha$, and $f$ is surjective.
- Assume $f(x_1) = f(x_2) = \alpha = 2^{m_1} + \dots + 2^{m_k}$, then we must have $$f(x_1) = \sum_{y\in x_1} 2^{f(y)} = 2^{m_1} + \dots + 2^{m_k} = \sum_{y\in x_2} 2^{f(y)} = f(x_2),$$ and we must have $x_1 = \{m_1, \dots , m_k\} = x_2$, so $f$ is injective.

*Find the function $g$*
Not solved.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution for Part A looks good.

For Part B, just compose $f^{-1}$ with the function mapping two sets to the ordered pair, and again with $f$. After you realize what $g$ is doing it is fairly straightforward to write it explicitly too.

Comment: Thanks for reassuring me about part A :) And thanks for the tip regarding $g$!

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Asaf that your solution to Part A looks fine.

For Part B, I would recommend just going through the calculation<sup>1</sup> of
$$\large
f(\langle x,y \rangle )
= f ( \{ \{ x \} , \{ x,y \} \} ) 
= 2^{f(\{ x \})} + 2^{f(\{x,y\})} = \cdots$$
and then make the replacements $f(x) = n$ and $f(y)=m$.

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>This assumes that you are using the Kuratowski definition of ordered pairs; if you are using a different definition, make the appropriate changes.</sub>

Comment: Thanks for reassuring me about part A :) Regarding the function $g$, I'm getting that $f(\langle x,y\rangle) = 2^{2^n}(1 + 2^{2^m})$. So ... just define $g(n,m) = 2^{2^n}(1 + 2^{2^m})$? It still bugs me that it says $g:\omega \to \omega$ though. Shouldn't it say $g:\omega \times \omega \to \omega$?

Comment: @Maethor: Yikes! I didn't see that the problem specified $g : \omega \to \omega$; I saw $g(m,n)$ which sort of implies that the domain of $g$ is $\omega \times \omega$ instead of $\omega$.  Unless you have a fixed "pairing function" (as Asaf mentions) which injects $\omega \times \omega$ into $\omega$, I'm not sure how to overcome this incongruity.